# How to determine if a object type is a built in system type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I am writing a simple `List<t>` to CSV converter. My converter checks the all the `t`'s in List and grabs all public properties and places them into the CSV.

My code works great (as intended) when you will use a simple class with a few properties.

I would like to get the `List<t>` to CSV converter to also accept the System types such as String and Integer. With these system types I do not want to get their public properties (such as Length, Chars etc). Thus I would like to check if the object is a System type. By System type I mean one of the built in .Net types such as `string, int32, double` etc.

Using GetType() I can find out the following:

```
string myName = "Joe Doe";

bool isPrimitive = myName.GetType().IsPrimitive; // False
bool isSealed = myName.GetType().IsSealed; // True 
// From memory all of the System types are sealed.
bool isValueType = myName.GetType().IsValueType; // False

// LinqPad users: isPrimitive.Dump();isSealed.Dump();isValueType.Dump();
```

How can I find if variable myName is a built in System type? (assuming we don't know its a string)

Comment: What do you consider a system type and what not?

Comment: I do not know the correct terminology but I consider `string`, `int32` to be a system type and `Employee` is obviously not. Basically any type that was not created by the compiler.

Comment: Are you looking for only the types built into the compiler? Or all types in the `System` namespace?

Comment: @Gabe ohh I see where you're going, just compare the root namespace to "System"?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`myName.GetType().Namespace`

This will return System if it is an in-built type.

Comment: This answers the question but does not solve the problem. How do you know that all value types in the `System` namespace are ones that you can ignore the properties of? Do you really want to do this to `System.ArgIterator` or `System.Nullable<Employee>`?

Comment: Namespace-based methods potentially may cause collisions. See the following comment for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44682414/6627992

Comment: @NetMage , programmers may extend system namespace with custom types in different assemblies. If we will be use string namespaces we may get incorrect results because this types is not *the language build in* 
(new System.CustomType().GetType().Namespace) == "System"

Comment: @Makeman Nice, though I wouldn't have called that a collision.

Comment: @NetMage for me it looks like a possible naming collision.

Answer (score 60):

Here are a few of the several possibilities:

- `myName.GetType().Namespace == "System"`
- `myName.GetType().Namespace.StartsWith("System")`
- `myName.GetType().Module.ScopeName == "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary"`

Comment: @JeremyChild `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms` type has `Module.ScopeName` equals to `System.Security.dll` so not only one `"CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary"` should be checked. I'v added check like `moduleScope == "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary" || moduleScope.StartsWith("System") || sourceType.Namespace.StartsWith("System") || sourceType.Namespace.StartsWith("Microsoft")`

Comment: The module scope name test does not seem to work with .NET Core. `typeof(string).Module.ScopeName` and `typeof(List<string>).Module.ScopeName` both return `"System.Private.CoreLib.dll"`.

Answer (score 16):

If you are unable to define precisely what a "built in system type" is then it seems likely that you won't know what types are in any answer given. More probably what you want to do is just have a list of the types that you don't want to do this with. Have a "IsSimpleType" method that just does a check against various types.

The other thing that you may be looking for is Primitive Types. If so look at:

Type.IsPrimitive (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx)

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32,
>   UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

This doesn't include string but you could add that on manually...

See also [How To Test if Type is Primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442534/how-to-test-if-type-is-primitive)

Answer (score 10):

Namespace-based methods potentially may cause collisions.

There is an another reliable and simple way:

```
static bool IsSystemType(this Type type) => type.Assembly == typeof(object).Assembly;
```

Or a little bit more optimal, caching the system assembly:

```
static readonly Assembly SystemAssembly = typeof(object).Assembly;

static bool IsSystemType(this Type type) => type.Assembly == SystemAssembly;
```

Comment: Try this with `System.Windows.Point`.

Comment: 'System.Windows.Point' is not the language *build in* system type like object, int, string, DateTime, TimeSpan etc. Seems that this question is about build in types.

Comment: I would disagree with what is being called built-in: why should `Action<,,,,,,,>` (8 args) be different from `Action<,,,,,,,,>` (9 args)? Or why should `System.Collections.Hashtable` or `System.Collections.ArrayList` be built-in but `System.Collections.BitArray` not? Or `System.IO.FileAttributes` not but `System.IO.FileOptions` be built-in?

Comment: @NetMage if we consider classical .NET Framework 4.7.2, all this types included into mscorelib assembly, except Action<,,,,,,,,> (9 args) from System.Core. So, you may customize list of build-in assemblies according your own vision. I just want to say that comparison of Assemblies is more safe then comparison of string namespaces.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the best possibility:

```
private static bool IsBulitinType(Type type)
{
    return (type == typeof(object) || Type.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object);
}
```

Comment: Just a warning: Type.GetTypeCode() can return a non-object code if the object implements IConvertible and returns something else: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx

Comment: If an object property is a string, it would return true here.
If the intent is to determine if the type is a custom type then this wouldn't work.

Comment: `System.TimeSpan` is lost

Answer (score 3):

I was building something reflectively and found that the `IsSecurityCritical` property *seemed* to work for this purpose; however, this was only because the trust-level for *my* assembly wasn't high enough to flip that bit.

A bit of a laugh; thankfully I found this question and will be adjusting accordingly.

**Note**: The `IsSecurityCritical` property only exists if .NetFramework > 4

I will likely go with; the following from a previous answer.

> myName.GetType().Module.ScopeName == "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary"

But, with a couple tweaks; such as making it an extension method on `Type` and using a `const` for **CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary**

Comment: Have you check with CoreCLR to ensure that ScopeName remains the same?

Answer (score 0):

Given the caveats surrounding the existing answers, I am going to suggest a Windows only solution:

```
public static class TypeExt {
    public static bool IsBuiltin(this Type aType) => new[] { "/dotnet/shared/microsoft", "/windows/microsoft.net" }.Any(p => aType.Assembly.CodeBase.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(p));
}
```

Presumably there is a similar path on other supported operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
colType.FullName.StartsWith("System")
```

rather then

```
colType.Namespace.StartsWith("System")
```

becose `Namespace` may be null.