# How to find all types that used in specific type properties recursively in C# .NET Core?

Tags: c#

See this code

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<long,float> No {get;set;}
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Manager
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public List<string> Phones { get; set; }

    }
```

How to find all types that used in specific type properties recursively ? 
for example

**GetAllInternalTypes(typeof(Manager))**

*Result for Manager: (Manager => User => Person)*

- int
- User
- List< User >
- Person
- List< string >
- string
- DateTime
- Dictionary< long,float >
- long
- float

I want to find all used Types of an specific type recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little bit tricky. because you want to only get properties of your types not built in types of .Net libraries. for example `Dictionary`, `String`, `DateTime`, `Array` etc, have their own properties that you want to exclude. fortunately there are ways to know if type is your defined type or is from `System` library.

[How to determine if a object type is a built in system type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932580/how-to-determine-if-a-object-type-is-a-built-in-system-type)

Also I preferred to return `PropertyInfo` instead of `Type` because it gives more information, if you want to only get Type of properties you can easily do that using linq.

```
var types = properties.OrderBy(p => p.DeclaringType).Select(p => p.PropertyType).Distinct().ToList();
```

Here is the algorithm with simple test

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var properties = GetTypes(typeof(Manager));

    foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1,-20}{2}", 
            propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name, 
            propertyInfo.DeclaringType?.Name,
            propertyInfo.Name);
    }
}

public static List<PropertyInfo> GetTypes(Type type)
{
    if (type.Module.ScopeName == "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary" || // prevent getting properties of built-in type
    type == type.DeclaringType)                                    // prevent stack overflow
    {
        return new List<PropertyInfo>();
    }

    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    List<PropertyInfo> result = type
        .GetProperties(flags)
        .SelectMany(p => new[] {p}.Concat(GetTypes(p.PropertyType)))
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have two problems 1- does not work on .NET Core 2- your code can not get inner types of Dictionary, Array, Tuple, List, Collection and ...

Comment: by inner types you mean generic types? it can be accessed by this property. `type.GenericTypeArguments`. for example for `Dictionary<long, float>` it will give two types `long` and `float` in array. if given type is not generic this array is empty. note that in the solution I give you can access this property with this `propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments`.

Comment: what do you mean it does not work on .NET core 2, what error do you get?

Comment: I know how access to any type I dont know how write it recursively !!! see this example : Tuple<List<Person>,Tuple<int,List<Dictionary<long,Manager>>>,DateTime,List<List<User>>>