# Determine if CodeElement belongs to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Visual Studio 2015. I have command that gets added to the context menu when a project is right clicked and I can get the project that was right clicked. Now what I am trying to do is determine if the project contains a class that implements a certain interface. So my first step is to get the classes in the project. So I did something like this:

```
protected IEnumerable<EnvDTE.CodeClass> GetClasses(EnvDTE.CodeElements elements, 
                                                   EnvDTE.Project project)
{
    foreach (EnvDTE.CodeElement element in elements)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(element.InfoLocation);

        var cls = element as EnvDTE.CodeClass;
        if (cls != null)
        {
            yield return cls;
        }
        var ns = element as EnvDTE.CodeNamespace;
        if (ns != null)
        {
            foreach (var childCls in GetClasses(ns.Members, project))
            {
                yield return childCls;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this will go through and pull out classes. The problem is that it will go through everything that is referenced include BCL classes. I thought using `InfoLocation` might help, but everything returns `vsCMInfoLocationExternal` (presumably because in the context where the plugin is running, they are external). I've tried things like `element.ProjectItem` and `element.ProjectItem.ContainingProject` and `element.Parent` with the hope of comparing that to the parent project, but those all throw `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`. So is there a way, given that I know the project, to determine if a particular `CodeElement` is part of the project, or just referenced by the project?

**EDIT:** The best I've been able to come up with so far is to do this, first get the default namespace for the project:

```
var defaultNS = project.Properties.Item("DefaultNamespace").Value.ToString();
```

And then I can do this:

```
if (ns != null && ns.Name == defaultNS)
```

So now I won't go drilling down into `System`, which is good. The only problem would be if a project had multiple namespaces that I wanted to search. I can't figure out if there is a way to get a list of namespaces that are defined *in the project*.

Edit: The suggested dupe deals with `Type` so isn't entirely relevant.

Comment: I'm marking this as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174921/how-do-i-determine-if-system-type-is-a-custome-type-or-a-framework-type because there really is no way to do this inside or outside of a vs extension.

Comment: @PaulSwetz: It may be that there is no way to do it, but the suggested dupe isn't the same thing and isn't helpful here. I don't have the `Type`, I have a `CodeElement`, so suggestions involving `Type` aren't relevant.

Comment: I could put up an answer that round about does what you want by figuring out what class/enum/structs it encounters in a codeelement come from external reference vs in solution definitions. It *may* fit your needs, cant say it very efficient though because its highly recursive.

Answer (score 1):

This may suit your needs or it may not but this is what I used to parse code elements and figure out if the definition is in the solution or if it comes in via a reference. There is no way to know if the reference is 3rd party vs BCL however. Some code removed for brevity since this is inside an API and hard to fully break out. You could add a trick once you have the types full name and know its a reference where you reflect all dlls that are signed with the Microsoft key for the type name, if you find one its bcl, otherwise it *probably* is not.

```
 public static string CodeElementAsTypeFullName(EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element));
        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass
            || element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEnum
            || element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementStruct)
            return element.FullName;
        else
            return ((dynamic)element).Type.AsFullName;
    }
protected void FlattenElement(EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 element)
{                        
        try
        {
            string varType = CodeElementAsTypeFullName(element);               
            switch (element.Kind)
            {
                case vsCMElement.vsCMElementVariable:
                case vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty:
                {
                    EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 defined = null;
                    ///this is API, basically  a collection of all the files in the solution with all class/enum/stuct defs parsed out into collections.
                    foreach (SquishFile file in this.solutionFiles)
                    {
                        //next line goes through each solution file one by one to figure out if the file defines the class/enum/struct definition.
                        defined = file.ContainsCodeElement(varType);
                        if (defined != null)
                            break;
                    }
                    if (defined != null)
                    {
                        if (defined.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass
                                        || defined.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementStruct
                                        || defined.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEnum)
                                    //THE ITEM IS DEFINED LOCALLY!    
                    }else
                      //the item is a reference
         }
        }
    }
     public class SquishFile
{        
    public ConcurrentBag<CodeClass> ClassDefinitions = new ConcurrentBag<CodeClass>();
    public ConcurrentBag<CodeEnum> EnumDefinitions = new ConcurrentBag<CodeEnum>();
    public ConcurrentBag<CodeStruct> StructDefinitions = new ConcurrentBag<CodeStruct>();

    protected ProjectItem _projectItem;
    public ProjectItem ProjectItem { get { return _projectItem; } }
    public SquishFile(ProjectItem projectItem)
    {
        if (projectItem.FileCodeModel == null)
            throw new Exception("Cannot make a squish file out of a project item with no FileCodeModel!");

        _projectItem = projectItem;
        foreach (EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 ele in projectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements)
            Discovery(ele);
    }

    public EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 ContainsCodeElement(string fullName)
    {
        foreach(EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 ele in ClassDefinitions)
            if (ele.FullName.Equals(fullName))
                return ele;
        foreach (EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 ele in EnumDefinitions)
            if (ele.FullName.Equals(fullName))
                return ele;
        foreach (EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 ele in StructDefinitions)
            if (ele.FullName.Equals(fullName))
                return ele;
        return null;
    }
    protected void Discovery(EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 element)
    {
        if (element.IsCodeType && element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass)
            this.ClassDefinitions.Add(element as EnvDTE80.CodeClass2);
        else if (element.IsCodeType && element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementEnum)
            this.EnumDefinitions.Add(element as EnvDTE.CodeEnum);
        else if (element.IsCodeType && element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementStruct)
            this.StructDefinitions.Add(element as EnvDTE80.CodeStruct2);
        foreach (EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 ele in element.Children)
            Discovery(ele);
    }
}
```